# How to list all Gradle projects in multi-project build

Tags: gradle

I have a project with several Gradle modules (I think Gradle just calls these sub-projects). Basically I have a bunch of projects/modules listed in `settings.gradle`. Is there a Gradle command to print each one (either name or ideally a supplied label/description)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Unspectacularly, that task is simply called "projects", and (if you are using the Gradle wrapper) `./gradlew projects` executed at the root project lists all sub-projects.

In general, if you are looking for a task, your chances are good that you can guess its name from the task list shown by `./gradlew tasks`.

Comment: Is there any way to do this programmatically inside the build.gradle.kts file?

Comment: Sure, just use something like `allprojects.forEach { println(it.name) }`. Use `subprojects` instead if you do not want to include the root project.

Comment: Unfortunately those two approaches return different results. I'm using included builds. The ./gradlew projects returns the root project and all the included projects in the way I's expecting. But, the allprojects variable contains only the root project of my build. subprojects is empty, childprojects is also empty. Maybe this is a bug in Gradle DSL?

Comment: The with `gradle.includedBuilds`.

Answer (score 0):

From within a module's build.gradle.kts, you can use:

```
rootProject.allprojects.forEach {
    println("Project: ${it.name}")
}
```